# Не прокладывается путь до папки со стилями

Tags: php, html, css

Пишу сайт на php. Когда мой файл в папке не корневой, то путь до стилей не могу поставить, почему то неверное строится. скриншоты прикладываю.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: при обновление страницы стиль появляется на секунду и исчезает

Comment: Покажите header.php

Comment: дополнил пост скриншотом

Comment: скорее надо не`/assets...`, а `./assets....` т.е. относительный путь

Comment: не хочет так. мне надо из папки brawl/page/add_hero/ выйти в brawl/assets . но, все стили в header.php, который в папке brawl. и там в файле header.php и идет ссылка на стили

Comment: @АлексейШиманский не надо плохому учить )

Comment: перепробовал уйму вариантов. на старой наработке работает - тут нет

Comment: используй полный путь от корня диска